# Price search on multiple variant row using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a below price table

[image: Temp_attr table with different variant product with price]

required each product have a multiple prices in single row

my sql query is

```
 select a.out_of_stack, product.*,
   ( select min(price) from temp_attr
     where product_id =product.product_id
   ) as min_price ,
   ( select max(price) from temp_attr
     where product_id = product.product_id
   ) as max_price from product
 left join users a
 on a.user_id = product.user_id
 where product.category_id in (37903,4707)
   and product.product_status in ('0')
   and product.draft=0
   and a.active=0
   and product.product_close=0
   and product.price between 10 and 4000
 group by product.product_id
```

i need to get the product when search using price with temp_attr table.

Comment: At least make some attempt to format the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find Max/Min prices for products in `temp_attr` :

```
 SELECT MIN(price) , MAX(price) from temp_attr group by product_id
```

Join them with `product` and `user` tables:

```
  SELECT a.out_of_stack , product.*, t1.* FROM
  product
  left join (SELECT MIN(price) , MAX(price) from temp_attr group by product_id ) as t1
  on t1.product_id = product.product_id
  left join users as a
  on a.user_id = product.user_id
  where product.category_id in (37903,4707)
    and product.product_status in ('0')
    and product.draft=0
    and a.active=0
    and product.product_close=0
    and product.price between 10 and 4000
  group by product.product_id
```